# Can we copy Apache Ignite Cluster to another Ignite cluster?

Tags: ignite

I want to back up entire Ignite cluster so that back up clutser will be used if the original(active) cluster is down. Is there any approach for this?

Comment: Yes..kindly go through the official docs.refer :http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/primary-and-backup-copies

Comment: Thanks @Akshay. But my question is how to copy entire cluster (consisting of two or three nodes)  into other clutser(with same number of nodes). Basically it means recreation of  cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If you need two separate clusters with replication across data center, it would be better to look at GridGain solutions that supports Datacenter Replication. 
Unfortunately, Ignite does not support DR.

With Apache Ignite you can logically divide you cluster to two zones to have guarantee that every zone contains full copy of data. However, there is no way to choose primary node for partitions manually. See, [AffinityFunction](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#affinity-function) and affinityBackupFilter() method of standard implementations.

Answer (score 0):

As answered above, ready  made solution is only available in paid version. Open source Apache ignite provides ability to take cluster wide absolute [snapshot](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/snapshots/snapshots). You can add a cron job in your ignite cluster to take this snapshot and add another job to copy snapshot data to object storage like S3.

On the other side, you download this data node wise to work directories of respective nodes as per [manual restore](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/snapshots/snapshots#manual-snapshot-restore-procedure) procedure and start the cluster. It should automatically activate when all baseline nodes are started successfully and your cluster is ready to use.